Ruff linting rule for importing from "highest" available module
In my Python project, I have a structure akin to this:
a/
 - __init__.py
 b/
    - __init__.py
    c.py

Where an object C is defined in c.py, and a/__init__.py exports this object:
from a.b.c import C

__all__ = ["C"]

Is there a Ruff linting/formatting rule to prefer C to be imported as
from a import C

instead of
from a.b.c import C

I was hoping to get ruff (or isort?) to complain when I use the "long form" (from a.b.c import C), and recognize that this import can be done as from a import C.

I doubt it – as far as I know, Ruff doesn't do cross-module analysis of any sort right now.
